# PHP Function that shows status of systemctl service

Tags: php

I'm trying to make php function that shows the current status (either active or inactive) of a systemctl service (like apache or nginx).

Here's my code:

```
function isactive($service) {

    if (shell_exec("systemctl is-active $service") == "active ") {
        echo "<td style=\"color: green;\">Active</td>";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<td style="color: red;">Inactive</td>';
    }

}
```

The var_dump of `active` is:

```
    string(7) "active "
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a look at the help section and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Your question has been flagged as needing editing because it doesn't have a clear problem statement.  Specifically, what is wrong with the code that you wrote?  What makes that output incorrect?

Comment: The "whitespace" you think you see if you dump the return value of `shell_exec()` is probably a newline character, not a space. This is why the comparison with `"active "` doesn't evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @axiac I don't think so; if I `var_dump` a string with a newline character in, it gets represented as a literal new line in my terminal, not as a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, there's the code

```
    function isactive($service) {
    $output = shell_exec("systemctl is-active $service");
    if (trim($output) == "active") {
        echo "<td style=\"color: green;\">Active</td>";
    } 
    else {
        echo '<td style="color: red;">Inactive</td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but what was wrong with the code that you already had? Why did this fix it? I'm kind of confused; I don't see a reason that the code in the question shouldn't've worked as it stood, given the `var_dump` output you showed.